# Promise and Arrow Function in Angular2

Tags: angular, promise, angular-promise

I am new to angular and it may sound silly but I didn't get how this code works

```
this.ms.getList().then((hl) => { this.HeroesList = hl; });
```

I called the service method, on success what it returns ?

Secondly, how this arrow function got the array of heroes that my service has to return and then assigning the array to my component variable ,

My Component Code :

```
constructor(private ms: myService) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.ms.getList().then((hl) => { this.HeroesList = hl; });
  }
```

And here is the service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Hero } from './hero'
import { HeroesList } from './heroesList'
@Injectable()
export class myService {
    heroes: Hero[];
    getList(): Promise<Hero[]> {
        return Promise.resolve(HeroesList);//when success, return the list 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be easier to understand if you look at how the TypeScript is transpiled to JavaScript (ES5).

Your TypeScript:

```
this.ms.getList().then((hl) => { this.HeroesList = hl; });
```

Transpiled to JavaScript:

```
this.ms.getList().then(function(hl) { 
    this.HeroesList = hl; 
});
```

The Promise `.then()` function accepts two callback functions, one for a success callback and one for an error callback. You're only using the success callback. Therefore, when `.then()` is executed on your Promise, if your Promise is successful, it will callback to your defined success function. Your defined success function then sets your service variable to the resolved result of your Promise.

Comment: h1 is your response.

Answer (score 1):

When the promise resolves.. it is returning the heroeslist which is the h1 in the component then function.

Comment: Yes it means success. http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html. Read this for a better understanding of promises.

Comment: this.ms.getList().then((hl) => { this.HeroesList = hl; }); , how did hl get the array that my service returned with promise ? I dont get it,